# Does the article get dropped off when translating the latter part of psalm 77:3 [LXX]?

Tags: greek, grammar

A simple question: Does **οἱ** *not* get translated?

Psalm 77:3 in Rahlfs' LXX: "καὶ **οἱ** πατέρες ἡμῶν διηγήσαντο ἡμῖν,"

Literal, wooden translation: "and ___ fathers our told us,"

Answer (score 1):

After much consideration, I come to realize that **οἱ** doesn't need to be translated. I tried doing a Spanish translation where it does make more sense if translated (very wooden of course): "y **los** padres nuestros han transmitido a nosotros,"

NETS has: "and our fathers told us."

I have heard that there are times when an article doesn't need to be translated, hence my question regarding this article.

Comment: @Ruminator I don`t understand the problem with using NETS. A translation is never a primary source, but it does help understand the text

Comment: @Ruminator Thank you for the link, especially Mounce's! I was working on translating the Greek myself and then I was wondering about how and if to translate the article. Then I consulted NETS to check my work. Then I answered my own question. Posted my question too soon.

Comment: @b a I have to admit that NETS did help me to understand the text once I made my preliminary translation.

Comment: Comments should be deleted when you are done with them. I'm going to delete mine now. Peace.

Comment: Whatever is relevant to the exegesis please add to your answer and then delete the rest. Comments can be deleted at any time by the mods.